# Regarding the radio button in salesforce

Tags: salesforce, visualforce

I am searching for the solution regarding the radio button in salesforce apex programming.

The scenario is I have one object in that one field is updated with value  when the radio button is selected in which there are three options like settings1 =0, settings2 =1, settings3 = 2. After that if I select setting1  then when I come to same page through command link of settings page. Previously selected `[settings1]` is not in a selected state radio button. I have written query to get that field value but it is not showing the selected radio button previously selected.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the visualforce selectRadio tag? If yes, then have you set the value attribute to your object field?
Make sure to not mix up the Labels and Values, the object field has to store the value (0 if you selected settings1) and not the label (settings1) of the radio field.

Comment: Yes I am using visualforce tag selectRadio and the object field is saved with 0 when the settings1 option is selected.but when  we come to same page by command link  the radio button is not in  a checked state of setting1.

Comment: When you say come to same page, do you mean a postback? Seems like you are having problems regarding the order of execution of a page (I could be wrong). See this for the [Order of Execution for Visualforce Page Postback Requests](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_controller_postback_request.htm)